# Trying to get property of non-object in realtional Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Why my relational 'Trying to get property of non-object' ???

I have model **Destination** with hasOne() to model AddressDistrict

```
public function getDestinationAddressDistrict(){
return $this->hasOne(\common\models\AddressDistrict::className(), ['id' => 'DISTRICT']);
}
```

In model **AdressDistrict** any field : id, propinsi_id, nama

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'propinsi_id' => 'Propinsi ID',
            'nama' => 'Nama',
        ];
    }
```

---

In controller (actionIndex) I get model Destination :

```
$modelDestination = new Destination;
```

and I pass to *create* then I pass to *_form* ..

In *_form* I write `$modelDestination->destinationAddressDistrict->id` ..and I have that notify.. Any solution ?

Comment: in create  you have not a valid value for the relation  ..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have created a new instance of `Destination`, so all the fields are empty, so there is no way to get a valid relation based on a value of `DISTRICT`, as `DISTRICT` hasn't yet been set.

You have two options. You can either test for the existence of a valid relation, like this;

```
if ($modelDestination->destinationAddressDistrict){
    //Do something with the `$modelDestination->destinationAddressDistrict->id`
}
```

or you can assign a default value of `DISTRICT` so that a valid relation can be generated.